# Статические переменные и методы класса

Tags: c++, c++11

Как в современном (`c++11` и более позднем) объявлять статические переменные в классе и можно ли вообще это делать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class Class
    {
        static const short unsigned id = 1;
        static const string name = "Заголовок 1";

        public:
        static short unsigned getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        static string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    };

    cout<<Class::getId()<<' '<<Class::getName()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Я уже понял, что инициализировать статические переменные класса можно только либо из вне, или только если это константы, но не получается вообще никак.

```
g++ -Wall -march=native -msse3 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -o "oop" "oop.cpp" (в каталоге: /home/ilya/Downloads/Qt)
oop.cpp: В функции «int main()»:
oop.cpp:10:36: ошибка: локальный класс «class main()::Class» не должен иметь статический элемент данных «const short unsigned int main()::Class::id» [-fpermissive]
   static const short unsigned id = 1;
                                    ^
oop.cpp:11:30: ошибка: локальный класс «class main()::Class» не должен иметь статический элемент данных «const string main()::Class::name» [-fpermissive]
   static const string name = "Заголовок 1";
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
oop.cpp:11:23: ошибка: инициализация внутри класса статического элемента данных «const string main()::Class::name» нелитерального типа
   static const string name = "Заголовок 1";
                       ^~~~
oop.cpp:11:30: ошибка: вызов non-constexpr функции «std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [с _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]»
   static const string name = "Заголовок 1";
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Сборка завершилась с ошибкой.
```

И если определять из вне.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class Class
    {
        public:
        static short unsigned id;
        static string name;
    };

    Class::id = 1;
    Class::name = "Заголовок 1";
    cout<<Class::id<<' '<<Class::name<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

То всё равно не получается.

```
g++ -Wall -march=native -msse3 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -o "oop" "oop.cpp" (в каталоге: /home/ilya/Downloads/Qt)
oop.cpp: В функции «int main()»:
oop.cpp:11:25: ошибка: локальный класс «class main()::Class» не должен иметь статический элемент данных «short unsigned int main()::Class::id» [-fpermissive]
   static short unsigned id;
                         ^~
oop.cpp:12:17: ошибка: локальный класс «class main()::Class» не должен иметь статический элемент данных «std::__cxx11::string main()::Class::name» [-fpermissive]
   static string name;
                 ^~~~
Сборка завершилась с ошибкой.
```

Почему так происходит и что я делаю не так?

Comment: Наверное, вы путаете области видимости статических членов класса, когда они уже находятся в объектах.

Comment: Не совсем понял о чём вы. Я просто хочу объявить статические свойства и методы (в PHP так называют переменные класса и функции-члены класса), что бы к ним обращаться через класс не создавая экземпляр этого класса. Подобное можно сделать просто объявив переменную и ф-ию в пространстве имён, но в пространствах имён, как минимум, нет наследования и модификаторов доступа.

Comment: Согласен с областями видимости я запутался.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обратите внимание на ошибку. Там упоминается, что класс локальный.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Class
{
public:
    static const int id; // можно инициализировать тут
    static const std::string name; // нельзя инициализировать тут
};

const int         Class::id{111};
const std::string Class::name = "rectangle";

int main()
{
    std::cout << Class::id << ' ' << Class::name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Можно убрать константность, инициализация от этого не пострадает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Class
{
public:
    static int id;
    static std::string name;
};

int         Class::id{111};
std::string Class::name = "rectangle";

int main()
{
    Class c;
    std::cout << c.id << ' ' << c.name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Во втором примере можно обращаться по имени класса и далее через `::`, я просто привел для примера через экземпляр и `.`  Также рекомендую обратить внимание на фигурную инициализацию, через `{}`, как сделал для `id`, она имеет ряд преимуществ, но иногда стоит быть осторожнее, потому что из нее получается объект `std::initializer_list`. Что касается инициализации внутри класса, то это возможно, если мы имеем статическую константу и интегральный тип:

```
class Curious
{
    static const int c1 = 7;     // правильно, но помните об определении
    static int c2 = 11;          // ошибка: не константа
    const int c3 = 13;           // ошибка: не статическая константа
    static const int c4 = f(17); // ошибка: инициализатор не константа
    static const float c5 = 7.0; // ошибка: не интегральный тип
    // ...
};
```

Если (и только если) Вы используете инициализированный член таким образом, что требуется хранить его в памяти, как объект, член должен быть где-нибудь (один раз) определен. Инициализатор не может повторяться:

```
const int Curious::c1;       // это определение, но не повторяйте здесь инициализатор
const int *p = &Curious::c1; // правильно: Curious::c1 был определен
```

Comment: Благодарю. Получается, если у меня не константы, а переменные, то записать в них значения всё равно можно только 1 раз, даже из той же самой области видимости, где находится класс?

А почему так получается, читать можно откуда угодно, а записывать только из той же самой области видимости?

Comment: Нет. Записать значения в статические переменные можно сколько угодно раз. Добавьте в main строчку c.id =666; и значение изменится.

Comment: Можно и так поменять в main: Class::id =666; - статические переменные должны быть инициализированы в той же самой области видимости.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь разобрался.

Comment: Это получается что переменные должны быть только публичные, что бы их возможно было про инициализировать?
Через публичный метод приватные переменные никак нельзя проинициализировать?

Comment: Более того, если вынести из `main()`, то `const int Class::id{111};` можно и не писать вне класса - такую целочисленную константу компилятор поймет и так: https://ideone.com/c79yu0